# Accessing JSON value when key has special character

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, url

I have the following JSON object, which I'll call `data`.

```
{
  "topalbums": {
    "album": {
      "image": [
        {
          "#text": "http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/34s\/88057565.png",
          "size": "small"
        },
        {
          "#text": "http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/64s\/88057565.png",
          "size": "medium"
        },
        {
          "#text": "http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/126\/88057565.png",
          "size": "large"
        },
        {
          "#text": "http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/300x300\/88057565.png",
          "size": "extralarge"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In an angular controller, I call this JSON object `data.topalbums.album`.

Back in my HTML page, I'm trying to insert the last (3rd) image from the image aray, using `ng-src`:

`ng-src="{{album.image[3].#text}}"`

This of course cause angular to throw an Lexer Error, due to the `#` character.

I've tried escaping the character with no luck:

`ng-src="{{album.image[3].%23text}}"`

How can I access the value of the `#text` key in the JSON object's `image` array?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you can access those properties with `[]` brackets:

```
ng-src="{{album.image[3]['#text']}}"
```

https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-property-accessors